# How to use dropdown picker inside every FlatList item in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-dropdown-picker

I am using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker) to show drop down picker option. It's working fine when i am using it without FlatList (Screenshots attached)

But when i am using it inside FlatList view, picker's children view is going behind next FlatList row's view (Screenshots attached)

I have also tried to use zIndex  in Desc order for picker.

It's been a very long time I am with this problem and didn't get anything to make things happen.

How things can get solved?
Any other way to show dropdown children in UI and it's selectable?[image: normal view of this dropdown]

[image: children hide below next] FlatList child content

Render code for each FlastList child is geven below,

```
<View >
                <Card style={{ elevation: 10, margin: 7 }}>

                     <Card.Content style={{ backgroundColor: '#B5DBF7' }}>
                          <View style={{ marginTop: 3, }}>

                               <View style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}>
                                    <Text style={{ color: CONSTANTS.COLOR.BASE_COLOR, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.text}</Text>
                                    <View style={{ marginTop: 10, width: '100%', height: 1.5, backgroundColor: CONSTANTS.COLOR.BASE_COLOR }}></View>
                                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, marginTop: 3 }}>This will be descriptive text for notification of the user. Dummy data is being showing now.</Text>


                               </View>

                               <DropDownPicker
                                    items={[
                                         { label: 'USA', value: 'usa', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />, hidden: true },
                                         { label: 'UK', value: 'uk', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" /> },
                                         { label: 'France', value: 'france', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" /> },
                                    ]}
                                    // defaultValue={this.state.country}
                                    containerStyle={{ height: 40 }}
                                    childrenContainerStyle={{
                                         height: 1030
                                     }}
                                    style={{ backgroundColor: '#fafafa', zIndex: index_value - index, position: 'relative'}}
                                    itemStyle={{
                                         justifyContent: 'flex-start'
                                    }}
                                    dropDownStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fafafa', height: 100, }}
                                    onChangeItem={item => this.setState({
                                         country: item.value
                                    })}
                               />
                          </View>
                          
                     </Card.Content>
                </Card>
           </View>
```

Comment: give your parent view a flex: 1 like: <View style={{flex: 1}}> </View>

Comment: How did you fix it ?

Comment: Still no answer?